# How to generate QR code for every prediction?

Tags: flutter, dart, machine-learning, qr-code

I've created a mobile app with Flutter framework that can predict laptop prices. Now, I want to add a special functionality: for every prediction the user does, I want the app to generate a QR Code with the price, so that another user scan it, and it will automatically fill his characteristics like the other user.
[image: Characteristics forum]
[image: Characteristics forum]
[image: the price of laptop, under it, i want to generate a QR code]

Comment: Please provide a code sample instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your QR code generator string must contain all characteristics that the creator entered
Ex.:
User **x** created a computer with 16GB ram & Core i7 7700HQ etc..
the generator string should be
`{"ram":"16gb","cpu":"i7 7700hq",...}`
you can use a `Map<String, String>` for the entered characteristics and use `jsonEncode(yourMap)` to convert it to string and pass it the the QR Code generator

when the receiver scan the QR Code, he will get `{"ram":"16gb","cpu":"i7 7700hq",...}`, use `jsonDecode(yourMap)` to reconvert the string to `Map<String, String>` characteristics in your receiver's device, predict the price according to what you got in the map

Comment: should i create a database or not? or i just create an api for QR Code

Comment: You don't need any database type because all the information you need should be stored in the QR Code, you can put whatever data you want in the qr code,
just try to put some unique key to validate that the QR code was generated by your app to avoid exceptions, `{"qr_source":"pc_predictor","ram":...}` and check for the key `qr_source`, if it exists and valid (same as you put it), let you magic flow, otherwise show a warning that the QR code is not valid

Answer (score 0):

there is a package called qr_flutter you can throw data to it and it will generate a QR code for the user

package : https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter